# Spring security oauth2 + keycloak login with custom login menu

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm working on a spring boot application that uses a keycloak authorization server. The resource server also acts as the oauth client, storing user access/id tokens. The server only provides an API which is currently secured using the authorisation code grant type. This means that a login is conducted through a redirect to keycloak's login page.

Since we're only building an API at the moment, which will later be used by some frontend devs, we don't want to use keycloaks login page and instead make our own or alternatively just provide some "login" endpoints that accepts a username/email and a password.

I have been researching ways of doing this for a while now. What I'm looking for seems to be the "resource owner password credentials" flow, however, some source claim its deprecated / shouldn't be used. What are my alternatives? Is it possible to provide a "login endpoint" with oauth2? If so, how would I implement it with spring security?

Currently the only thing thats come to my mind is just requesting the tokens from my auth server manually, returning the ID token so it can be saved as a cookie and then if then "informing" spring security about the login somehow so it adds the access token to the repository and automatically validates the token and handles authorisation if a protected resource is requested.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to handle this is described in [OAuth 2.0 for Browser Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps)

- A Spring Boot backend that serves as the [Backend for Frontend (BFF) Proxy](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-14#section-6.2) which is the confidential OAuth2 client that does Authorization Code flow and brokers to Keycloak using Spring Security `http.oauth2Login` and proxies calls to the Resource Server using the [ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/reactive/function/client/ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.html)
- A Spring Boot Resource Server using Spring Security `http.oauth2ResourceServer`
- Keycloak with customized Login UI via the [LoginFormsProvider](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/2ec3f33d5b0b06df872d7319cfa2417f448ae10a/server-spi-private/src/main/java/org/keycloak/forms/login/LoginFormsProvider.java#L35) SPI (typically extending [FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/2ec3f33d5b0b06df872d7319cfa2417f448ae10a/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/forms/login/freemarker/FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider.java#L99)) and [custom theme](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes)

Resource Owner Password Credentials is not recommended. You can refer to [RFC 6819 OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6819#section-4.4.3).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `authorization_code` flow to authenticate users against any OAuth2 authorization server. Period.

If you concern is look and feel, what you can do is style the Keycloak forms [using a "theme"](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes).

As a side note, if your app is solely a REST API, I'd advise that you configure it solely as a resource server. It allows to make it "stateless" (no session), which makes it natively scalable and fault tolerant. Of course, OAuth2 resource server can be queried only by OAuth2 clients and [according to latest recommandations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), this clients should be on your servers too, but you could use `spring-cloud-gateway` with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `TokenRelay=` filter for that purpose (this is [how I proceed](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff)).

Comment: Is there no way of using a custom html page for the login? For example we might want a "forgot password" button or a link to our custom sign up menu. perhaps there is a different auth server provider that allows custom html login menus?

Comment: User login and registration are the responsibility of authorization server (Keycloak in your case, but it's the same with any other). The client only initiates the flow and exchange authorization code for tokens. So, **no, this customization won't happen in your clients, it will be done on the authorization server**. Many authorizations servers allows quite some customization of there UI and features, but little propose as much as Keycloak does. Just open the manual.

Comment: Hm okay, so the way I understand it the only way of having complete control over the login UI would be to build our own auth server which would be a lot of work. Is forking keycloak and customizing the html templates an option?

Comment: I find it "funny" that you are thinking of forking an OIDC provider project (one that has been written by experts over years) before grasping OAuth2 basics, reading the project manual, or even getting interested in its feature list :D